# Is there any way to connect my flutter ios project to firebase from WIndows?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

This is my very first flutter project. I do not have Mac pc/desktop . Sources from web instructs to approach rental methods. I cannot afford those techniques. I have to add IOS app using android studio or Vs Code. Help me out please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible add iOS to flutter without install xcode in your machine, so you need run project with mac OS

But for learning purpose you can install mac os on VMware and develop on it, but for publish app on itune store you need export binary from physical mac computer.

Comment: Yes its working 100% same as mac computer 
https://medium.com/@buildsometech/how-to-install-macos-on-vmware-in-windows-pc-mojave-a79329e057db

Comment: Thank u very much Sir. One more thing I want to clarify. I have created a flutter project on my windows and linked Android portion to firebase.. Next with the help of Virtual Box  can I open existing iOS portion of flutter from virtual xcode and link to firebase?